# Custom Button with Multiple NavigationLink

Tags: button, swiftui, navigation

I want to be able to use my custom button in multiple places. Right now it can only Navigate to StartWithPhoneView when tapped. When I use somewhere else I want to Navigate to another view too. I can do it by creating two custom buttons but it is code repetition.

```
struct CustomButtonView: View {
@State var isTapped: Bool = false
var text = ""
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print("Create account tapped")
        self.isTapped.toggle()
    }, label: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.205, height: 44)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .overlay(Text(text))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    })
    .padding(.top,15)
    NavigationLink("", destination: StartWithPhoneView(), isActive: $isTapped)
}
```

}

I am using Custom Button in this SignUpView

```
struct SignupView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            CustomButtonView(text: "Create an account" )
        }
        NavigationLink("", destination: StartWithPhoneView(), isActive: CustomButtonView.$isTapped) // I want to reach inside CustomButtonView to fetch isTapped
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Generic` type **which is a View**

```swift
  struct CustomButtonView<Destination: View>: View { //<-here
    @State var isTapped: Bool = false
    var destination: Destination //<- here
    var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Create account tapped")
            self.isTapped.toggle()
        }, label: {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.205, height: 44)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .overlay(Text(text))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        })
        .padding(.top,15)
        NavigationLink("bbbbb", destination: destination, isActive: $isTapped) //<- here
    }
}
```